# Delphi TXmlDocument: Unexpected attribute name / Cannot set xsi:type

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing

I'm using Delphi 2007 with `TXmlDocument` and `IXmlNode` to set the `xsi:type` attribute to a new xml node but I'm getting a different result than expected.

```
with fieldNode do
    begin
        Attributes['xmlns:xsi'] := 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
        Attributes['xmlns:xsd'] := 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';
        Attributes['xsi:type'] := 'FieldImage';
        Attributes['xmlns'] := '';
    end;
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
<SerializableField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="FieldImage" xmlns="">
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
<SerializableField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="FieldImage" xmlns="">
```

The `xsi:` part is missing. Is this a known bug in Delphi or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

Using the console app provided in the answer below, the resulting XML was as expected with the correct `xsi:type` attribute. I cannot recreate that in my app. Its a delphi.net app if that makes any difference?

I have produced a work around where the XML is dummped to a string and a string replacement is performed but it seems unnecessary and a bit dirty...

Comment: Please check my answer on your system, this could be an msxml version issue

Comment: what do you mean with Delphi.net, is the application made in Prism? What you need to do is provide an MVCE (like I did) which produces the problem.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Delphi for .NET (AKA Delphi 8) was Borland's attempt to get into the .Net platform dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [`IXMLNode.DeclareNamespace()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.DeclareNamespace) method when declaring XML namespaces (the `xmlns` attributes), do not use the [`IXMLNode.Attributes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.Attributes) property directly.  Doing so merely creates the attributes, but does not let the DOM know the namespaces actually exist.  `DeclareNamespace()` will generate the necessary `xmlns` attributes, as well as register the namespaces in the DOM so the underlying XML engine can use them when creating new nodes/attributes.  This is important so that child nodes can inherit their parent's namespace correctly.

When setting an attribute that is in a namespace, you can use the `Attributes` property, or you can use the [`IXMLNode.SetAttributeNS()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.SetAttributeNS) method instead.

Try this:

```
with fieldNode do
begin
  DeclareNamespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
  DeclareNamespace('xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
  Attributes['xsi:type'] := 'FieldImage';
  // alternatively:
  // SetAttributeNS('type', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'FieldImage');
  DeclareNamespace('', '');
end;
```

This produces the expected XML:

```xml
<SerializableField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="FieldImage" xmlns="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an MVCE (what you should have provided) in Delphi XE7/Win10:

```
program SO41263595;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  XmlIntf,
  XmlDoc,
  ActiveX,
  SysUtils;

procedure Test;

var
  Doc : IXMLDocument;
  Node : IXMLNode;

begin
 Doc := LoadXMLData('<test><node/></test>');
 Node := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0];
 Node.Attributes['xmlns:xsi'] := 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
 Node.Attributes['xmlns:xsd'] := 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';
 Node.Attributes['xsi:type'] := 'FieldImage';
 Node.Attributes['xmlns'] := '';
 Writeln(Doc.XML.Text);
end;

begin
  try
    try
     CoInitialize(nil);
     Test;
    finally
     CoUninitialize;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

This gives the correct output:

```
<test><node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="FieldImage" xmlns=""/></test>
```

If this MVCE produces the same problem as yours then it could be a Delphi bug or a MSXML library issue (for which TXMLDocument is a wrapper).

Comment: The console app produces the expected `xsi:type` attribute, even when saved to file.